# When can a polynomial equation graph look like a superposition of other graphs?

Tags: geometry

I saw the following example from a calculus textbook I have:

$$x + y^3 - xy = 1$$

and they show a graph. It looks like a parabola with a line through it, the line horizontal. But this is a degree-3 polynomial, and it produces graphs of degree-2 and degree-1 equations superposed together.

This makes me wonder: can you get a superposition of other graphs, like two parabolas cutting through each other, or a parabola and a line with the line cutting the parabola in more than one point, or an independent line and parabola? Or one with a circle? All from one polynomial? If so, what are examples? If not, why not? What sorts of these superpositions are possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning the example given in your book, consider $$f(x,y)=x+y^3-x y-1=0$$ If $y=1$ $f(x,1)=0$ and this gives the straight line.

On the other side $f(x,y)=0$ can write $x(1-y)=1-y^3$ and, if $y \neq 1$, this leads to $x=1+y+y^2$ which is a parabola.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question, which is whether or not other combinations of these features are possible. Are they?

Comment: I totally agree with you ! I just consider the case given in the book. The remaining is a quite broad answer. Suppose that the function $F(x,y)=0$ could be factored as $F(x,y)=\prod_{i=1}^nf_i(x,y)$, then the total graph will be the superposition of all $f_i(x,y)=0$ graphs. Is this better ?

Comment: And, in particular, $x+y^3-xy-1$ factors as ....

Comment: ... $(-x + y^2 + y + 1)(y - 1)$. There's the line and the parabola. Cool.